# .NET TextBox does not update SelectedText value after calling Select

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I have a .NET Winforms-based program I wrote in C# where I programmatically select text within a TextBox using the `Select()` method.  I can see the selected text on the screen and the `SelectionLength` member reports an accurate amount of selected characters, but the `SelectedText` member doesn't contain any text:

```
int indexPeriod = strLectureText.IndexOfAny(terminators, indexStart);

thisTextbox.Focus();

if (indexPeriod > -1)
{
    thisTextbox.Select(indexStart, (indexPeriod - indexStart) + 1);
}
else
{
    thisTextbox.Select(indexStart, thisTextbox.Text.Length);
}

Log.Debug("jtext len=" + thisTextbox.SelectionLength + " txt=" + thisTextbox.SelectedText);
thisTextbox.ScrollToCaret();
```

What's going on?

Update Nov 16 2013

I am adding additional code per @KingKing's request:

```
delegate void delegateMoveToNextTextFragment(ref TextBox thisTextbox, char[] terminators);
private void MoveToNextTextFragment(ref TextBox thisTextbox, char[] terminators)
{
 string strLectureText = String.Empty;

 strLectureText = thisTextbox.Text;
 int currentStartPos = thisTextbox.SelectionStart + thisTextbox.SelectionLength - 1

 // search the rest of the buffer after the currently-selected string to find the next period
 int skipLastChar = 0;

 // don't include last selected character in search
 try
 {
      if ((thisTextbox.SelectionLength > 0) & (strLectureText[currentStartPos] != '.'))
  {
       skipLastChar = 1;
  }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
      Debug.WriteLine("exception caught! ex=" + ex.Message);
  skipLastChar = 0;
 }

 int indexStart = 0;

 if (currentStartPos == 0)
 {
      indexStart = 0;
 }
 else
 {
      indexStart = currentStartPos + 1;
 }

 int indexPeriod = strLectureText.IndexOfAny(terminators, indexStart);

 if (indexPeriod > -1)
 {
      thisTextbox.Select(indexStart, (indexPeriod - indexStart) + 1);
 }
 else
 {
      thisTextbox.Select(indexStart, thisTextbox.Text.Length);
 }

 thisTextbox.Focus();
 Log.Debug("jtext len=" + thisTextbox.SelectionLength + " txt=" + thisTextbox.SelectedText);
 thisTextbox.ScrollToCaret();
```

}

Comment: can we see some code?

Comment: can you add the xaml as well?

Comment: What xaml are you referring to?

Comment: is this winforms or wpf?

Comment: Winforms.  I just copied a code snippet from my form.

Comment: @gonzobrains where do you run the code? it's strange that **it works for me** (I can get the correct `SelectedText`)

Comment: I'm running it on my local computer as a windows form.

Comment: The fact that it works for you makes me want to test it again.  I think I might try putting it in a small test app and seeing if that changes things.

Comment: This method is being called via a delegate with Invoke().  The textbox is passed as a ref argument.  Could any of that matter?

Comment: @KingKing Another thing:  I get the correct SelectedText on the first try, but subsequent calls don't work until I manually highlight the text with the mouse again.

Comment: @gonzobrains looks like you should post your actual code to make it clear because the code you posted seems to work OK.

Comment: @KingKing I added the entire method now.

Comment: @gonzobrains now I tested your code and it worked OK. I highly doubt that when you tried your code, the caret is located at the end of your TextBox. Try setting to the some starting index you want using `SelectionStart`. Otherwise I can't think of any cause for your problem. Also you mentioned about using `Invoke` with your delegate, please add code for that call too. Looks like you have some `threading stuff` related here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40666/discussion-between-gonzobrains-and-king-king)

Comment: @gonzobrains I don't think you have any other solution without involving `SelectedText`, as I said, the problem may be somewhere else in your code (especially the `Invoke`...). You should also try debugging carefully, sometimes we can't solve it without debugging.